Is it possible to draw a quadratic and cubic with real coefficients that do not intersect?
I found this question as an exercise in the TMUA notes, but I'm confused as to how to prove it algebraically.
My intuition tells me that there will always be a real solution because cubics steep faster than quadratics, therefore they will always meet.

Cubic - quadratic is still cubic, and the new cubic has at least one real root.

Their difference is another cubic.
Such a cubic would he zero for at least one real root.
Therefore ... .
